# iterate over nested objects to find the key attribute and return that object- Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, filtering

I have a parent object and multiple child objects, here is the structure:

```
parent: {
  child1: {
    "aaa": {values: [], type: "string", title: "AAA"},
    "bbb": {values: [], type: "string", title: "BBB"},
    "ccc": {values: [], type: "string", title: "CCC"},
    "ddd": {values: [], type: "string", title: "DDD"}
  },
  child2: {
    "eee": {values: [], type: "string", title: "EEE"},
    "fff": {values: [], type: "string", title: "FFF"},
    "ggg": {values: [], type: "string", title: "GGG"},
    "hhh": {values: [], type: "string", title: "HHH"}
  },
  child3: {
    "iii": {values: [], type: "string", title: "III"},
    "jjj": {values: [], type: "string", title: "JJJ"},
    "kkk": {values: [], type: "string", title: "KKK"},
    "lll": {values: [], type: "string", title: "LLL"}
  }
}
```

now I have a function which returns one of the child value as of the keys of the child objects. ex:

```
function childVal() {
  //do somehting 
  return "aaa";
}
```

now depending on this value I would like to get the entire child object, ex: if returned value is `"bbb"`, I looking to return the object that has the `"bbb"` key which in this case is `child1`.

so output for follwoing values:

```
"aaa": return child1;
"ggg": return child2;
"bbb": return child1;
"lll": return child3;
```

is this possible?

Comment: You didn't close the double-quote at the end of `"lll": {values: [], type: "string", title: "LLL"}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function parentFilter(parent, myFilter) {
    return Object.values(parent).filter(child => Object.keys(child).some(key => key===myFilter));
}

let parent = {
       child1: {
      "aaa": {values: [], type: "string", title: "AAA"},
      "bbb": {values: [], type: "string", title: "BBB"},
      "ccc": {values: [], type: "string", title: "CCC"},
     "ddd": {values: [], type: "string", title: "DDD"}
    },
      child2: {
    "eee": {values: [], type: "string", title: "EEE"},
      "fff": {values: [], type: "string", title: "FFF"},
      "ggg": {values: [], type: "string", title: "GGG"},
     "hhh": {values: [], type: "string", title: "HHH"}
    },
      child3: {
    "iii": {values: [], type: "string", title: "III"},
      "jjj": {values: [], type: "string", title: "JJJ"},
      "kkk": {values: [], type: "string", title: "KKK"},
     "lll": {values: [], type: "string", title: "LLL"}
    }
 };
    
console.log(parentFilter(parent, 'aaa'));
console.log('-----------');
console.log(parentFilter(parent, 'ggg'));
console.log('-----------');
console.log(parentFilter(parent, 'bbb'));
console.log('-----------');
console.log(parentFilter(parent, 'lll'));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const parent = {
       child1: {
      "aaa": {values: [], type: "string", title: "AAA"},
      "bbb": {values: [], type: "string", title: "BBB"},
      "ccc": {values: [], type: "string", title: "CCC"},
     "ddd": {values: [], type: "string", title: "DDD"}
    }, 
        child2: {
    "eee": {values: [], type: "string", title: "EEE"},
      "fff": {values: [], type: "string", title: "FFF"},
      "ggg": {values: [], type: "string", title: "GGG"},
     "hhh": {values: [], type: "string", title: "HHH"}
    },
   }


const val = 'aaa';  
Object.keys(parent).forEach(el => {
  if(parent[el][val] !== undefined) {
    console.log(parent[el][val].values)
  }
})
```

Comment: this is great, thans much

Answer (score -2):

Loop through all the properties, and check whether the given key is one of the properties of that object.

```
function childVal(key, parent) {
    return Object.values(parent).find(o => o.hasOwnProperty(key));
}
```